# How to Display JavaScript Objects? every object in new line

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to print the each array object to get printed in new line

```js
var person = [{
    name: "Ajay",
    age: 37,
    city: "New York"
  }, {
    name: "jon",
    age: 30,
    city: "New York"
  },
  {
    name: "kallu",
    age: 38,
    city: "New York"
  }
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h2>JavaScript Display Object</h2>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want it to display like

```
Ajay : 37 : New York
jon : 30 : New York
kallu : 38 : New York
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your object values are always in the same order, you can extract them using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and then use [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) twice, first to join the object values with a `:`, then to join each set of values with a `<br>` element:

```js
var person = [{name:"Ajay", age:37, city:"New York"},{name:"jon", age:30, city:"New York"}, 
{name:"kallu", age:38, city:"New York"}];

const html = person.map(o => Object.values(o).join(' : ')).join('<br/>');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

If your object values are not necessarily in the same order, you can just enumerate them in order:

```js
var person = [{name:"Ajay", age:37, city:"New York"},{name:"jon", age:30, city:"New York"}, 
{name:"kallu", age:38, city:"New York"}];

const html = person.map(o => [o.name, o.age, o.city].join(' : ')).join('<br/>');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```